# Is it possible to condense arrays in a mongoose query?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following schemas

```
var book_s = new Schema({
        //_id: automatically generated,
        pageCount: Number,
        titles: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'BookTitle' }]
    });

var bookTitle_s= new Schema({
        //_id: automatically generated,
        language: String,
        title: String
});
```

If I use a query like the following: `Book.find({}).populate('titles').exec()`

I will get a list of all titles for each book.

Is there a way to alter the query so that I can pass in a language paramater (say, English), and populate only the English titles into the Book model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `match` field in your [`populate`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-populate) call to only populate those models that pass its conditions:

```
Book.find({}).populate({path: 'titles', {match: {language: 'English'}}}).exec()
```

Comment: What about when you only want a single entry from an array within the model? (I have updated the schema to reflect this question)

Comment: @RavenDreamer That's a very different question.  I don't think there's a way to do that.

Comment: Unfortunate. I suppose it's time to take a look at reworking my schema, then.

Comment: You can limit within the populate object using the options property. `{path: 'titles', {match: {language: 'English'}}, options: { limit: 1 }}`